# Question about reading effective c++ item 4(replace non-local static variable with local static variable)

Tags: c++

```
class FileSystem {
...
int numDisks();
...
};

FileSystem& theFileSystem() // this replaces the theFileSystem object
{
    static FileSystem fileSystem; // define and initialize a local static object
    return fileSystem;
}

class Directory {...};

Directory::Directory()
{
...
std::size_t disks = FileSystem::theFileSystem().numDisks();
...
}
```

[The book](https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/C/Addison.Wesley.Effective.CPP.3rd.Edition.May.2005.pdf) asks us to replace non-local static variable with local static variable, but when we call `FileSystem::theFileSystem().numDisks()` multiple times, it will declare `static FileSystem fileSystem` multiple time which should not be good, right?

Comment: `static FileSystem fileSystem` will exist only one time.

Comment: A local _non-static_ variable is created for every call of function (and destroyed when leaving the scope it is located in). For local `static` variables, it's completely different: They are created (and initialized) at latest when the function is entered the first time. Afterwards, the existing instance is re-used (and granted to be always the same). In this case, being local has a different valuable effect: It makes the variable "invisible" outside the function.

Comment: Btw. the _They are created (and initialized) at latest when the function is entered the first time._ works even in multi-threading. That's what [Meyers Singleton](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/thread-safe-initialization-of-a-singleton#h3-1-meyers-singleton) is based on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [@jkb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11207416/jkb) and [@Scheff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7478597/scheff),  local static variables only exist once and you can't declare non-local static variable twice.

```
void test(){
    static int i = 0;
    i++;
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    test(); // 1
    test(); // 2
    test(); // 3
    static int j;
    static int j; // error
    return 0;
}
```